# Why is the set of singular hypersurfaces a hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I get it that we can identify an algebraic hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\newcommand\P{\mathbb P}\P^n$ as a point in $\P^N$ where $N=\binom{n+d-1}{d}-1$. We just identify the coefficients of the monomial of the homogenous polynomial defining the hypersurface with coordinates in $\P^N$. But I have read somewhere that the set of singular hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\P^n$ are actually a hypersurface in $\P^N$. I don't see this immediately. For conic sections, it's easy: To get the degenerate conic sections, I just get the determinant of the Hessian of its defining quadratic form and have an equation on the coefficients of the quadratic form and so I get the defining equation of a hyperplane in $\P^5$. What is the defining equation of this hyperplane in $\P^N$ in general?

**Edit:** I just figured out that this has to do with the *mixed resultant*. I completely forgot about this. A good reference for this is the book by Gelfand, Kapranov and Zelevinsky: *Discriminants, Resultants and Multidimensional Determinants*. This was also asked in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401552/dimension-of-the-set-of-singular-hypersurfaces) post in Mathoverflow. I could add this (and more detail) as an answer post. I would wait a bit if someone else wants to add more.